# How to upgrade applozic SDK?

Tags: android, ios, applozic

We have used `applozic sdk` to develop a chat application(app) for android and ios. Is there any detailed documentation on how to update the SDK in the Android and IOS  application?
Will just copying the folders `mobicomkit`, `mobicommons` and `mobicomkitui` folders achieve the task or are there any scripts to update the SDK in the android and ios project files?

Comment: u can use cocoapods for updating frameworks in ios. check there latest version :  https://cocoapods.org/pods/Applozic

Answer (score 1):

One way is to fork the applozic respective GitHub repositories

a) For Android Applozic SDK you can fork repository from this GitHub link  https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Android-SDK and then you can do your own customization in mobicomkit or mobicommons or mobicomkitui modules in forked repository and commit and push the code changes which you have done to the forked git repo, if any new version comes then you can pull the changes from original master GitHub repo https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Android-SDK

b) For IOS Applozic SDK there is CocoaPods repository and without CocoaPods repository

1) If you added applozic sdk without CocoaPods :

- If you're using applozic ios sdk without CocoaPods then you can fork the git repo  https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-iOS-SDK and do your own customization changes and push it to the forked git repo whenever if you want to sync with master new changes then you can pull the changes from the master into your forked repo if you have any merge conflict then you should resolve those

2) If you added  applozic sdk as CocoaPods

- If you're using applozic ios sdk as CocoaPods in your project, if you want to do any changes in a pod then you can fork the pod applozic repo from GitHub link https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Chat-iOS-Framework and then you can do your own changes in the forked repo and commit and push it to your own forked repo you can check this link to point to custom pod check this [link](https://docs.applozic.com/docs/ios-chat-theme-and-customization#section-customise-pod)